# How does thread number map to CPU unit in ECS task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am using ECS Fargate as my web application deployment. And I'd like to support 200 per second request for my app. I see there is a task size from where I can configure CPU and Memory. And I wonder if I configure 1024 CPU unit with 2048MG memory, how many threads my app can support? Can I say this configuration support open up to 1024 thread in my process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 vCPU = 1024 CPU units. [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html):

> You can determine the number of CPU units that are available per Amazon EC2 instance type by multiplying the number of vCPUs listed for that instance type on the Amazon EC2 Instances detail page by 1,024.

---

> And I wonder if I configure 1024 CPU unit with 2048MG memory, how many threads my app can support?

It's impossible to say, you have to run a load test and measure this.

> Can I say this configuration support open up to 1024 thread in my process?

This would generally depend on which technology you use and what exactly a "thread" is.
But most probably you won't be able to run 1024 threads on 1024 CPU units (which is just one vCPU).